# ArchUnit test sensitive variable naming

Tags: java, archunit

Setup:

```
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-boot.version>2.7.0</spring-boot.version>

        <junit-jupiter-engine.version>5.8.2</junit-jupiter-engine.version>
        <mockito-junit-jupiter.version>4.6.1</mockito-junit-jupiter.version>

        <archunit.version>1.0.0-rc1</archunit.version>
```

In my recent Java 17-Project **Arch Unit Tests** are used.

It works fine so far and I'd like to extend the tests by **blacklisting** specific variable names.

**Target:** The question is not about "does it makes sense" - it is about "how to do it".

---

Sample Examples to get into my mood:

a) **Blacklisting** an Uuid.class to be named 'uuid'.

- Developers therefore have to use the allowed name 'id' or think of a more specific name regarding their purpose.

Sample Class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.UUID;

public record myClassRecordClass(
    UUID id,
    UUID uuid,               <-- forbidden
    UUID pupilId,
    UUID teacherId,
    String className
) implements Serializable {}
```

b) **Blacklisting** an 'until now used term' within a business case, as it has to be renamed.

- Falling back into the 'old habit/naming convention' shall be prohibited.

---

Nov. 2022: As far as I know **classes, fields and members** can be checked via ArchUnit, but **not variable names**.

In case the following PR might cover the issue ... https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/768
... somewhen in the future.

Nevertheless, did I miss a better solution?
Is there any other way to tackle the issue?

Best wishes   :)

Comment: FYI: [Arch Unit 1.0.0](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/releases/tag/v1.0.0) has been released more than 6 weeks ago! 

Comment: And note that [ArchUnit#768](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/issues/768) is not a PR, but a just feature request.

Answer (score 3):

For the specific case of [`record`s](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395), the parameter names are also field names, and therefore caught by

```java
@ArchTest
ArchRule no_field_named_uuid = noFields()
    .that().haveRawType(UUID.class)
    .should().haveName("uuid")
    .because("developers have to use the allowed name 'id' or " +
            "think of a more specific name regarding their purpose");
```